# Determine Which Control In My WPF Has Focus Via Script

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to determine which control has focus in C# ?

Example :

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Update(Brushes.White, textBox);   /*Here there my textBox has focus.*/

    //... (some codes)

    NotCorrect();

    //... (some codes)
}

private void NotCorrect()
{
    Update(textblock.background, /*I mean here : the focus remains where it is already, on the textBox.*/);
    textBlock.text = "Try again..."
}

private void Update(Brushes myBrush, Control myControl)
{
    texBlock.Background = myBrush;
    myControl.Focus();
}
```

In the NotCorrect() method :

textBlock.Background means : I want the same brush as the one already existing (see the first line of the Click event), I do not want to change anything.

(I prefer to write textBlock.Background rather than rewrite Brushes.White.)

Now I ask if there is also a way to say : I want the focus to remain on the control on which it is already, I do not want to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **I found out a kind of solution using null :**

  ```
  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      Update(Brushes.White, textBox);

      //... (some codes)

      NotCorrect();

      //... (some codes)
  }

  private void NotCorrect()
  {
      Update(textblock.background, null);
      textBlock.text = "Try again..."
  }

  private void Update(Brushes myBrush, Control myControl)
  {
      texBlock.Background = myBrush;
      if (myControl != null)
          myControl.Focus();
  }
  ```
- **Another simpler solution I found is to use `this` :**

  ```
  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      Update(Brushes.White, textBox);

      //... (some codes)

      NotCorrect();

      //... (some codes)
  }

  private void NotCorrect()
  {
      Update(textblock.background, this);
      textBlock.text = "Try again..."
  }

  private void Update(Brushes myBrush, Control myControl)
  {
      texBlock.Background = myBrush;
      myControl.Focus();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Form.ActiveControl is you should search for.

Comment: thank you for answering but it doesn't seem to work. I will understand better if you write a correct line of code.